# Is it safe to use this image uvicorn-gunicorn-starlette-docker for production?

Tags: docker, gunicorn, fastapi, uvicorn

I have to setup the server for the production environment and I'm using the [FastAPI framework](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/).

The [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/) of the framework suggests to use this docker image because it's ready and customizabile. So what I'll do is to expose my application using Gunicorn using the Uvicorn workers.

Is it safe?

Because I was reading some articles and they suggest to put NGINX as a Reverse Proxy in front of Gunicorn. In this case, the request is received by NGINX and then it decides where to route it. I can't understand the differences. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docker image is fine to use, but you should also put nginx in front of it as per the [gunicorn docs](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html#deploying-gunicorn). You could do this as a separate docker-compose service or in any other way, and configure nginx to pass all requests through to the gunicorn server.

The main reason for doing this is to protect yourself against denial of service attacks as gunicorn offers little protection here. If I remember correctly, it was/is susceptible to slow loris attacks and probably others.

Comment: Thank you! I found this implementation https://github.com/balassit/asgi-gunicorn-nginx-docker and it's what I needed to start to integrate NGINX in my Dockerfile.